# NullPointerException: storage == null

Tags: android, arrays

What could be the reason for the following stack trace :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null --------- Stack
>   trace --------- java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.(Arrays.java:38)
>   java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
>   mypackage.MyJava$5.onClick(MyJava.java:479)
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5205)
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21164)
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   ------------------------------- --------- Cause --------- -------------------------------

I tried assigning null to the items but this issue cannot be reproduced. Only few times this get reproduced i cant understand please help me..My code as follows

```
final String[] items= Global.currencycodes;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                builder.setTitle("Currency");
                builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, Arrays.asList(items).indexOf(((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.currency)).getText()), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
}
builder.create.show();
```

Here this exception from the line

> builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items,
>   Arrays.asList(items).indexOf(((TextView)
>   container.findViewById(R.id.currency)).getText()), new
>   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `Global.currencycodes` is null apparently..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Global.currencycodes` is null, making `items` null. When a null object is passed to `Arrays.asList()`, it complains.

Comment: yes Eric i tried in that way initialized Global.currencycodes=null; but this error canot be reproduced

Comment: I don't understand. Global.currencycodes should not be null.